# Why do I need two different classes to create the IntList object in Java?

Tags: java, class, object

I am studying the "Modern Programming Languages" from Adam Webber, and I just got started with Java. There is an example in the book on how to create new classes. In the example we try to define a new class, a list of integers. In order to do that, first we define the following class:

```
public class ConsCell {

private int head;
private ConsCell tail;

public ConsCell (int h, ConsCell t) {
    head = h;
    tail = t;
 }

public int getHead () {
    return head;
 }  

public ConsCell getTail () {
    return tail;
 }
}
```

Then, for some reason I don't understand, we create an extra class:

```
public class IntList {

private ConsCell start;

public IntList (ConsCell s) {
    start = s;
 }

public IntList cons (int h) {
    return new IntList(new ConsCell(h, start));
 }

public int length () {
    int len = 0;
    ConsCell foo = start;
    while (foo!=null) {
        len++;
        foo = foo.getTail();
    }
    return len;
 }
}
```

So, my question is why do we need the IntList class? Can't we define the methods length and cosn inside the ConsCell class, like this:

```
public class ConsCell {

private int head;
private ConsCell tail;

public ConsCell (int h, ConsCell t) {
    head = h;
    tail = t;
 }

public int getHead () {
    return head;
 }  

public ConsCell getTail () {
    return tail;
 }

public int length () {
    int hd = head;
    if (hd==null) return 0;
    ConsCell tl = tail;
    int len = 1;
    while (tl.getHead()!=null) {
        len++;
        tl = tl.getTail();
    }
    return len;
 }

public ConsCell cons (int newHead) {
    return new ConsCell (newHead, new ConCell(head,tail));
 }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It depends on the design used to implement the list. With a linked list, you often create a class to represent the entries.

Comment: if you call `length` on an arbitrary element of your list, you will receive the number of elements after that one, not the complete size of the list. Also, you need to keep track of the `start` cell.

Comment: You know this is just an example of object oriented programming, right?  You wouldn't write this particular code in real life.

Comment: Well you _could_ do it but you would have to use `getTail()` not `getHead()`... but the answers explain why you should have the wrapper class.

Comment: @Powerlord why is that ? It can definitely be improved (genericity, naming...) but it's a standard implementation of a linked list.

Comment: @Dici Because we're talking about Java, which has things like `List<Integer>` and [`IntSteam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) already.  I know I didn't specify which list there, but you'd choose the most appropriate one for what you're doing.

Comment: @Powerlord yeah... but that's fine to reimplement the most classical data-structures in order to master them. Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A cell is not the same as a list that is made of cells. Calling `length` on a cell and hoping to get the length of the list is bad semantics.

Since you are studying modern programming, take a look at the [Wikipedia article about cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons).

> cons constructs memory objects which hold **two values** or pointers to values. These objects are referred to as (cons) cells, conses, non-atomic s-expressions ("NATSes"), or (cons) **pairs**.

The word 'cons' has a specific meaning. It is not a list but a *pair* of *two values*. Such a pair can be **used** to build a list. That's why [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) is so beautiful. Complex things are build from very simple parts.

Answer (score 0):

It is mainly to allow empty lists, because `null` cell is not a very pretty way to represent it. One can also argue that a cell will offer low-level operations whereas the list has a more high-level interface. A cell may not be required to implement a list-like data-structure (for example, consider `ArrayList`), this is an implementation detail whereas the list itself is more conceptual.

Comment: Yes, that is also what the book says. But why doesn't the ConsCell class support the null list? Why can't I just create a null list by doing the following: ConsCell empty = new ConsCell(null,null);

Comment: That would not be an empty list, because you still have a node. BTW, it does not compile since an `int` can not be `null`. The empty list is a `null` node, so you can't manipulate it : `ConsCell empty = null; empty.length();` will result in a `NullPointerException`, for example

Answer (score 0):

A [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is usually composed by nodes, as depicted in this image:

[image]

In Object Oriented Programming, we can see there are two elements:

1. The node, that contains the data and a pointer to the next node in the list.
2. The whole list, that holds all the nodes inside it.

These two classes (node and whole list) are described in the classes by the author of the book you're reading:

1. `ConsCell` as the node, with an additional pointer to the previous node (head).
2. `IntList` that contains the starting node (`ConsCell start`) and that helps you to work with all the nodes starting from this one. This eases the client of the list to *interact* with the whole list rather than operate directly on the nodes and messing with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you don't understand is that the author of that book is implementing a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list).

It is a quite complex example for beginning, I mean a quite difficult first example class.

Why don't you try a simpler approach?
[BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) is a quite interesting environment for learning. You can find a [tutorial for beginners](http://www.bluej.org/tutorial/tutorial-201.pdf), and [another one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java-tutorial-downloads-2005894.html). Also some [examples](http://www.bluej.org/resources/demos.html) (unfortunately, some does not work).

And about that book... is it appropriate for beginners? The canonic book for Java is [Thinking in Java](http://www.mindviewinc.com/Books/TIJ4/), pretty recognized worldwide. You can even download 3th edition for free.

Hope this helps.